# putting text,csv,excel file in pattern

Tags: c++, python, g++-4.7

I am beginner for real programming and have the ff problem 
 I want to read  many instances stored in a file/csv/txt/excel
like the folloing

```
find<S>ing<G>s<p>
```

Then when I read this file it goes through each character and start from the six position and continue until the 11 position-the max size of a single row is 12

```
            -,-,-,-,-,f,i,n,d,i,n,0
            -,-,-,-,f,i,n,d,i,n,g,0
            -,-,-,f,i,n,d,i,n,g,s,0
            -,-,f,i,n,d,i,n,g,s,-,S//there is an S value next to the letter d
            -,f,i,n,d,i,n,g,s,-,-,0
            f,i,n,d,i,n,g,s,-,-,-,0
            i,n,d,i,n,g,s,-,-,-,-,G // there is a G value here at th end of g 
            n,d,i,n,g,s,-,-,-,-,-,P */// there is a P value here at th end of s
```

Here is the code that I tried in python. but can be possible in c++, java, dotNet.

```
import sys
import os
f = open('/home/mm/exprimentdata/sample3.csv')// can be txt file 
string = f.read()

a = [] 
b = []
i = 0
while (i < len(string)):

    if (string[i] != '\n '):
        n = string[i]
        if (string[i] == ""):
            print ' = '
                if (string[i] = upper | numeric)
                print rep(char).rjust(12),delimiter=','
        a.append(n)

    i = (i+1)


print (len(a))
print a
```

my question is how can I compare each string and assign a single char at the rightmost part (position 12 like above G,P,S)

how can I push one step back after aligning the first row?

how can i fix the length

please anyone see fragment and adjust to solve the above case

Comment: I have no idea what it is you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide some actual simplified examples of input files and what the corresponding output would be? (Instead of the rather confusing prose description of the algorithm you came up with that might as well be completely wrongheaded.) Basically: try to make your question a little more about the problem as well as the attempted solution.

Comment: I don't understand the following: "the ff problem", "<S>", "<G>" and "<p>".  Are the last three some kind of command or regular expression?

Comment: <S> <G> and <P> are taken from from the word Find<S>ing<G>s<P> where <S> indicates the end of "d" is root and  <G> end of "g" indicates gerund ... The aim is to generate the above word in a fixed size of array to be suitable for latter use .

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question.

But some advice:

Firstly, you should be closing the file after you open it.

```
f = open('/home/mm/exprimentdata/sample3.csv')// can be txt file 
string = f.read()
**f.close()**
```

Secondly, your indentation is problematic. Whitespace matters in Python. (Maybe your real code is indented properly and it's just a StackOverflow thing.)

Thirdly, instead of using a while loop and incrementing, you should be writing:

```
for i range(len(string)):
    # loop code
```

Fourthly, this line will never evaluate to True:

```
if (string[i] == ""):
```

string[i] will always be some character (or cause an out of bounds error).

I advise you read a Python tutorial before you try and write this program.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, how is this a valid answer?

Comment: sorry, for that I have lists of words with their morphological analysis and I want to  automatically generate those data in a way that suitable to be trained in machine which is a memory based learning.eg. the word "cats" manually analyzed as cat<Root>s<suffix>.this generated in windoing methods os fixed size arrays 'code' -,-,-,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,0                                             -,-,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,-,0  -,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,-,-,Root/                 continues until it finishes the line.and goes to the next line. if this is vague I will  add.

Comment: cat<root>s<suffix> analyzed as follows 'code' -,-,-,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,0 ////next line                                           -,-,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,-,0  ///next line                    -,-,-,c,a,t,s,-,-,-,-,Root 'code' sory fo messing up my post